# Why the value of ComboBox is not wriiten in the file?

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to write the values of combo box in the file with comma separated. but it only writing the commas in the file.

I have tried the casting to String. It didnt work.

```
File f=new File("C:\\Users\\najaf\\Documents\\BillingDetails.txt"); //writing in file
                FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f,true);
                BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(comboBoxOne.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxTwo.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxThree.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxFour.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxFive.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxSix.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxSeven.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxEight.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxNine.getEditor().getText());
                bw.write(",");
                bw.write(comboBoxTen.getEditor().getText());
                bw.newLine();
                bw.close();
                fw.close();
```

Expected:`2,5,,6,4,5`

Actual: `,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: Don't use the editor's value, it's unlikely to be the same as the selected value